# Kafka create topic with default number of partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to create a new Kafka topic from the command line

```
$ kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic def-test
```

I get the error

```
Missing required argument "[partitions]"
```

From the docs, I see that setting `num.partitions`, should have done the trick. I have the following in my `server.properties`

```
# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=2
```

But it is not taking effect. Also, I wonder how `kafka-topics` command which connects only to zookeeper and does not take any arguments to `server.properties` is going to be able to pick the correct value. How can I create topics without having to specify the number of partitions (by falling back to a default value specified elsewhere)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In kafka CLI , the number of partitions is a mandatory option.
The num.partitions is the default partitions for auto created topics.

One thing you can do is , enable auto topic creation using prop "auto.create.topics.enable" and then whenever there is a fetch or produce request for a non-existent topic, it will be auto created with the default partitions

Comment: Using version 2.13-2.6.0 and option --bootstrap-server server:port it in fact takes the number of partitions defined in the property num.partitions.

Comment: Step 3 of the quickstart suggests that partitions and replication-factor are optional https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart
Also, the options list provided by bin/kafka-topics.sh explicitly mentions that " If not supplied for create, defaults to the cluster default." (kafka_2.13-3.0.0)

Answer (score 29):

I was trying the [quickstart guide of Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart) and was facing this issue. As the guide suggests, I ran the following command,

`$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`

and got the following error:

`Missing required argument "[partitions]"`

As the error clearly states, we need to add more arguments to the command we use. For this you need to add `--partitions 1`. After this is added you will get the following error.

`Missing required argument "[replication-factor]"`

Do the same to this as well. Add the flag `--replication-factor 1`. So finally my command would look like

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
```

I hope this helps someone who is stuck with the quickstart guide. More on what these flags mean is given below.

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is weird, the kafka-topic.sh spec states the partitions param is optional but its actually NOT...

Answer (score 3):

You must add partitions and replication-factor too (not mentioned in the official doc.)

e.g.:
**--partitions 3 --replication-factor 1**
, so:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test-topic --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have such an error, your topic was created.
You can check this with such command:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Finally, yes this is optional. But implementation is a little bit confusing.